# Decrypt packet in lua dissector

Tags: encryption, lua, aes, wireshark-dissector

I am working on a custom dissector for Wireshark in lua.

Certain PDUs in the protocol is encrypted using AES and I would like to decrypt these so that I can show the clear content in Wireshark. Is this possible with a lua dissector and what APIs can I use to make the decryption?

Or do I need to make a c/c++ dissector to make a dissector that decrypts data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally i use [lua-crypto](https://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto) but it requires OpenSSL.
You can check [lua-wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CryptographyStuff).
Recently i create wrapper for [this](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/cryptography_technology/index.php) AES implementation called [bgcrypto](https://github.com/moteus/lua-bgcrypto-aes).
It has no external dependencies but i really do not use it yet in real work.

Comment: Interesting, would lua-crypto work on both OSX, Windows and Linux?

Comment: I use it on Windows. And I run tests on Linux Mint and on travis.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment Wireshark (2.0) does not expose a crypto API to LUA dissectors, so you have to implement it in the Lua dissector.

For a pure Lua solution you can use [lua-lockbox](https://github.com/somesocks/lua-lockbox) (as mentioned on the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CryptographyStuff)). This is not recommended if you need performance, but might be useful for prototyping.

Faster AES decryption implementations typically use a native library, for example:

- [LuaCrypto](https://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto) - uses OpenSSL, though it does not seem maintained
- [lcrypt](https://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto) - uses libtomcrypt, but there seems to be no development either

Since none of these libraries satisfied my needs, I developed a new one based on Libgcrypt for these reasons:

- Wireshark already links to Libgcrypt for things like SSL decryption.
- The Libgcrypt library supports sufficiently many ciphers and hashes.
- Libgcrypt is widely available and has an active development team.
- The Luagcrypt API is simple enough and documented.

The result is [luagcrypt](https://coveralls.io/github/Lekensteyn/luagcrypt) which works on the platforms supported by Wireshark (Linux, OS X, Windows). It is used in the KDNET dissector, this [commit](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/kdnet/commit/3dbd698daeac117a4d6b39a0d4d4dc2cddccd2f6) shows the transformation from lua-lockbox to luagcrypt.